# Who is the author of BayesSearchCV from scikit-optimize?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-optimize, bayessearchcv

I used BayesSearchCV from scikit-optimize for my manuscript. I searched online but I do not find a proper citation for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is:

> Head, T., Kumar, M., Nahrstaedt, H., Louppe, G., & Shcherbatyi, I.
> (2021). scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize (v0.9.0). Zenodo.
> https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.5565057

---

If you used a older version of the package, change the citation accordingly, e.g. if you click on [this link](https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.5565057) and look at v0.8.1, the citation is:

> Head, T., Kumar, M., Nahrstaedt, H., Louppe, G., & Shcherbatyi, I.
> (2020). scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize (v0.8.1). Zenodo.
> https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.4014775

Comment: Kindly refrain from answering off-topic questions, as advised in the [community guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions).

Comment: Ahh - sorry for the oversight